# how can I programmatically set the checkbox to true or false?

Tags: angular, typescript

```
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="balanced" [(ngModel)]="balancedAmount" (click)="onNoClick($event)">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
```

how can I programmatically set the checkbox to true or false?

TypeScript

```
  this.balancedAmount.checked = false;
```

Comment: I thought you could just bind the "checked" property to some state here?

Comment: Instead of using an object you can use boolean for model type in checkboxes. So you can just use `checked = false` and update the ngModel property to `[(ngModel)]="checked"`. This stackblitz example would also help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xbnwg1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a variable and toggle true or false and you can property bind that value to the [checked] property

```
 <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" id="balanced" [(ngModel)]="balancedAmount" (click)="onNoClick($event)" [checked]="this.balancedAmount.checked">
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
```

> this.balancedAmount.checked= true;